# Get Title and Description when Title item is clicked on Listview android

Tags: android, json, listview, android-arrayadapter

I use JSON to get data items Title and Description from a web server. I know how to parse it, use a custom Adapter and populate a listview with the Title only.. I want it to open a new activity and display the Title and Description of the clicked Item. Do I have to create a new custom adapter to populate this listview?  What should I pass from this side of the activity and how do I receive it on the other side?  Thanks in advance.

```
 displayTitleAdapter = new DisplayTitleAdapter(this, R.layout.rowlayout);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listviewfinal);
    listView.setAdapter(displayTitleAdapter);
    listView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

This is my  Adapter class' getView method

```
public View getView(int position,  View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
    View row;
    row = convertView;
    ReqHolder reqHolder;
    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflate = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflate.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        reqHolder = new ReqHolder();

        reqHolder.Title = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.title_title);
        reqHolder.Requirement = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.req_req);

        row.setTag(reqHolder);
    }
    else{
        reqHolder = (ReqHolder)row.getTag();
    }
    //Requirements is the model class with getter and setter methods for Fields Title and Requirement.
    Requirements requirements = (Requirements) this.getItem(position);
    reqHolder.Title.setText(requirements.getTitle());
    reqHolder.Requirement.setText(requirements.getRequirement());
    return row;
}

static class ReqHolder{
    TextView Title;
     TextView Requirement;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's works good :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Object o = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                UserConnected str=(UserConnected) o;//As you are using Default String Adapter
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),str.getPrenom(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I used this method to send the serialized class and @dh19 's method to receive it and it worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i did it for me, please make sure your modal class implements Serializable.

MainActivity:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("Question",questionArrayList.get(position));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

In my main activity i set an on item click listener on my listview and then start an activity using the intent class.

In my next class i get the object i put into the intent (question) ans display the text that i want to using getters and setters from my modal class

Acitvity 2:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activitiy_main2);
    Question q = (Question) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Question");

    TextView yourAnswer= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView correctAnswer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.description);

    yourAnswer.setText(q.getYourAnswer());
    correctAnswer.setText(q.getCorrectAnswer());
}
}
```

Hope this helped you out!